# .emacs c-mode/indent settings being ignored

Tags: indentation, config

I've been using Emacs forever now but more recently all of my new Linux setups start out with broken c-mode settings that I can't figure out how to fix. Changes in `.emacs` seem to have no effect, as if they're being overwritten by some other settings elsewhere. I keep reading that Emacs default is tab and 8 characters (I got Emacs 26 on Ubuntu 20.04) yet mine always defaults to 2 spaces instead even when I delete my `.emacs` file(s).

Googling this issue gets me no relevant results so it obviously must be something really stupid that I'm doing. How do i troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please share relevant portions of your config.

Comment: I've deleted my .emacs file and I expected it to default to 8 and using tabs. But if I create a new one and add this, nothing changes:

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)

Comment: Have you read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html and checked those locations? Have you `grep`'d for your troublesome settings in `~/.emacs.d/*`?